# Show fields in admin page only if user has specific rights

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm working on the Django admin site of an online shop, and I'm asked to enable a refund button only to a limited group of admins. The current situation, extremely simplified, is the following:

**models.py**

```
class ItemOrder(models.Model)
    [various fields and functions]
```

**admin.py**

```
class ItemOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ...
        ('Actions', {'fields': ['created', 'modified', 'refund_link']}),
        ]
    ...
    readonly_fields = [..., 'created', 'modified', 'refund_link']

    [other functions]

    def refund_link(self, order):
        ...
```

At the moment every user with the right to see this page can click on the refund link and refund  the order. I need to restrict its visibility/usability only to users who have a specific right. I tried with the `@permission_required` decorator, but the link is unusable for every user (it becomes "-" for anyone, even superusers). I also tried adding the `get_form` method to the `ItemOrderAdmin` class, but the refund link disappears completely for every user. This is how it was implemented:

**admin.py**

```
class ItemOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ...
        ('Actions', {'fields': ['created', 'modified']}),
        ]
    ...
    readonly_fields = [..., 'created', 'modified', 'refund_link']

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:  # Will be changed with a more specific right later
            kwargs['form'] = EventTicketOrderPersonForm
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

    [other functions]

    def refund_link(self, order):
        ...
```

**forms.py**

```
class ItermOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ItemOrder
        fields = '__all__'

class Meta:
    model = ItemOrder
    fieldsets = [
        ...
        ('Actions', {'fields': ['created', 'modified', 'refund_link']}),
        ]
```

This was copied from [the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form). I tried various variations of this. Mainly I tried removing the second Meta class in **forms.py** and the `refund_link` from the `readonly_fields` in **admin.py**, but the result is always that the link is missing for every user.

I have to say I'm quite new to Django, and some of the connections it makes between modules are still a bit magical to me. I suspect I'm missing something basic, but I can't find out what it is.

**Edit**: I managed to make forms work by commenting `fieldsets` and `readonly_fields`, but the result is far from what I need. Some fields are missing (the ones defined as functions inside `ItemOrderAdmin`, e.g. `refund_link`), all the fields are editable (only a few should be), and they are not divided into sets. It looks to me that forms are not what I'm looking for, but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have found the answer. Instead of specifying the `fieldsets` variable at the beginning of the class, I can define the `get_fieldsets` method, in this way:

**admin.py**

```
class ItemOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    ...
    readonly_fields = [..., 'created', 'modified', 'refund_link']

    [other functions]

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        fieldsets = [
            ...
            ('Actions', {'fields': ['created', 'modified', 'refund_link']}),
            ]
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            fieldsets[4][1]['fields'].append('refund_link')  # The 4 depends on the fieldsets structure.
        return fieldsets

    def refund_link(self, order):
        ...
```

I'll wait a few hours before approving my answer, in case someone comes up with a better solution, or there are major flaws in mine.